# Is there a 'programming buddy' type service that exists ?

Tags: consulting, consultants, helping

I am not sure how to ask this but the situation is I have a job where I do everything myself but once in awhile I will get stuck on small pieces and spend hours trying to find the answer that I am sure a advanced coder could find in under 5 minutes.

So I don't want to hire someone to code but just to be there on these times when I have a question and pay small amounts for the help here and there.

Can anyone help me ? I have tried fiverr but everyone is flakey.

Comment: What sites have you already tried? In Googling any programming problem, a few specific sites will almost always crop up.

Comment: What kind of job is this? Your company might not like you sharing their code with someone not under their contract.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping list question.

Comment: Not an actual answer to the question asked, but you might find [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sound like you want a contractor, that is: someone that you give an assignment and who then fixes your code.

But from what I'm understanding, it might that you're just looking for the wrong thing and that what you really need, is a [mentor.](https://www.codementor.io/)

(No affiliation with the site, I literally just googled "programmer mentor" and it was the first thing that popped up).

Comment: Yes.. Its somewhere between a contractor and stack overflow..  I appreciate SO for helping me but at the same time sometimes its easies to paste the code and ask for an answer.. But I don't expect people to want to debug my code for free..  The mentor site looks interesting.. I think what I am leaving out is at this job I am expected to know everything and create everything on my own but I'm just worried ill get stuck sometimers

Answer (score 18):

Yes, there is. It's called Stack Overflow, and it's free. Lots of great developers hang out there just to sharpen their skills on questions.

Comment: Yes.. I know this but sometimes it is hard to exaplain the problem and a lot easier just to give someone the code and I don't think stack overflow people feels like figuring out my code.. Obviously Id like to do everything myself but would like to have someone I could reach out to here and there and wouldn't mind paying a bit.

Comment: Nobody's going to just accept some block of code with a request to "fix it". Practice writing good questions. Practice building the minimum reproduction of the bug you're trying to fix. Get better at coding rather than asking someone else to do the hard parts.

Comment: @punkouter Why do you want to do everything by yourself? If you get stuck for several hours so frequently that you are considering a "programming buddy" service, perhaps you *should* actually hire somebody. You are asking for the impossible here. You want to solve the problems within 5 minutes, but you are not an "advanced coder" yourself, nor do you want to hire one. Perhaps you should improve your skills until you reach "advanced coder" levels before becoming a freelancer.

Comment: In my experience, taking the time to figure out how to phrase a problem is well worth the effort. The act of writing a questions out really brings my areas of confusion into focus. It forces me to learn more, reexamine my approach, and come back to write things a bit more coherently. So the effort it takes to form a good question is helpful and sometimes necessary. (A good percentage of the time, I answer my own question during the writing process.)

Comment: are you referencing [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I used to tutor for Chegg. You could probably hire a Chegg tutor, but they're best suited for solving high-school and college-level questions.